# How to prevent nhibernate from creating left outer joins for subclasses

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, criteria

When querying a base class NHibernate will create a left outer join for each of the base's subclasses. This happens even if the query is on properties only in the base and projections are set on those properties.

Example:

```
SELECT this_.Id as y0_, this_.Name as y1_ FROM AnimalBase this_ 
    left outer join Dog this_1_ on this_.Id=this_1_.AnimalBaseFK 
    left outer join Cat this_2_ on this_.Id=this_2_.AnimalBaseFK 
WHERE lower(this_.Name) like @p0;@p0 = '%rover%'
```

My question is how should I change this default behavior?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Look here:

**[How to perform a non-polymorphic HQL query in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093025/how-to-perform-a-non-polymorphic-hql-query-in-hibernate/2094321#2094321)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done because NHibernate uses polymorphic queries by default.
I mean, if you do this:

```
select * from Animal
```

NHibernate will try to retrieve all animals.  So, if you have a `Dog` class that inherits from `Animal`, it means that a Dog is an Animal.  (Which is logic , since inheritance describes an `IS-A` relationship).

You can disable this behaviour.
For more information: [Loading a base class through nhibernate incorrectly uses mappings from derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550188/loading-a-base-class-through-nhibernate-incorrectly-uses-mappings-from-derived-cl)

Comment: thanks Frederik. The link you gave led me to a better one at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093025/how-to-perform-a-non-polymorphic-hql-query-in-hibernate/2094321#2094321