# Non-polymorphic queries with Hibernate JPA (JPQL)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I post this question + answer as an extension to [How to perform a non-polymorphic HQL query in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093025/how-to-perform-a-non-polymorphic-hql-query-in-hibernate). It also highlights a change in behaviour between Hibernate 4.1.x and 4.3.5, as well as a bug if your mapping contains a `@DiscriminatorColumn` when not strictly needed.

I have a concrete superclass, Patient, with one concrete subclass, Amputee. Each has its own table ('patient' and 'amputee') and the Hibernate inheritance strategy is JOINED.

At first, as per the JPA spec, I opted for a `@DiscriminatorColumn` to distinguish Amputees from vanilla Patients in the primary `patient` table, using 'P' for vanilla patients and 'A' for amputees:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("P")

public class Patient {...
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="amputee")
@DiscriminatorValue("A")

public class Amputee extends Patient {...
```

JPQL query to select *all* patients, including vanilla and amputees (works fine):

```
select p from Patient p
```

JPQL query to select amputees only, not vanilla (works fine):

```
select a from Amputee a
```

JPQL query to select vanilla (*non*-amputee) patients only, using the TYPE operator:

```
select p from Patient p where type(p) <> Amputee
```

...works in Hibernate 4.1.3, but not in 4.3.5 (those are just the two versions I tested, maybe others too).

4.1.3 already generated some funky join and switch/case SQL, but at least worked. 4.3.5 generates *invalid SQL*, at least when using the mapping as described above. Here's the generated WHERE clause with the erroneous condition:

```
where case when patient0_1_.id is not null then A when patient0_.id is not null then 'P' end<>'A'
```

As you can see the "then A" bit should have had the A in single quotes, but doesn't, so the SQL fails. I was led to the solution by an obscure warning in the Hibernate log:

`WARN HHH000457: Joined inheritance hierarchy [cellnostics.model.Patient] defined explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  Legacy Hibernate behavior was to ignore the @DiscriminatorColumn.  However, as part of issue HHH-6911 we now apply the explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  If you would prefer the legacy behavior, enable the hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined setting (hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=true)`

Turns out that Hibernate does not need a `@DiscriminatorColumn` for SINGLE_TABLE or JOINED hierarchies: it issues a gymnastic join + case statement across all the involved tables. However, if you follow the JPA recommendation and *do* specify a `@DiscriminatorColumn` in such a mapping, Hibernate generates *invalid SQL* in version 4.3.5, while it generates clunky but at least working SQL in 4.1.3.

You can read more on the `@DiscriminatorColumn` issue on the [Hibernate JIRA: HHH-6911](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6911).

So, the solution is a mapping without `@DiscriminatorColumn`s:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)

public class Patient {...
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="amputee")

public class Amputee extends Patient {...
```

...which for the original non-polymorphic query:

```
select p from Patient p where type(p) <> Amputee
```

generates the correct SQL and returns the correct results:

```
where case when patient0_1_.id is not null then 1 when patient0_.id is not null then 0 end<>1
```