# How do i get insanceof object in spring data query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, instanceof

I have an `Item` class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Item {
    @Id 
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

And this two next class is subclass of `Item`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class RawMaterial extends Item {
    private String supplier;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Product extends Item {
    private BigDecimal salePrice;
}
```

I also have an `Inventory` class that have `Item` as field

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Inventory {
    @Id 
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne 
    private Item item;
}
```

My Question is how do i get the **instance of** `item` field. Is there something todo with `dtype`?

```
public interface InventoryDao extends JpaRepository<Inventory,Long> {

    @Query("FROM Inventory WHERE item instance of ?1")
    public List<Inventory> getInventoryByItem(Class klazz);

}
```

I need to do something like

```
List<Inventory> list = getInventoryByItem(Product.class);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093025/how-to-perform-a-non-polymorphic-hql-query-in-hibernate maybe

Comment: Thanks.. i will try it :)

Comment: So why not use a repo per concrete class?

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy I want to make a "small framework" which is the only concrete class is the class that extends Item class. Ex: Product and RawMaterial, maybe later i will have other class. In this question, i simplify my code to help my helper to understand my question. In the real code, it have some other method. 

The Inventory is my reusable class. It have a some other field, but the changable field of Inventory is the "item" field only. 

My code now has been evolve. I use a generic type for Item field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by my self.

```
public interface InventoryDao extends JpaRepository<Inventory,Long> {

    @Query("FROM Inventory WHERE TYPE(item.class) = ?1")
    public List<Inventory> getInventoryByItem(Class<? extends Item> klazz);

}
```